# Border Bottom Kept to certain length rather than 100%

Tags: css

With media query on phones I need to reduce border bottom of buttons on hover to a certain px, how is this done?  On laptop below works fine and is just the length of the word but on phone the border bottom is 100% of the screen and too long.

```
@media (min-width:299px) and (max-width:567px){

 .region-li{
   display: block;
   margin-right:20px;
   margin-left:20px;
   font-size:16px;
   font-family: 'codec_cold_triallight';
   color:#666666;
   padding: 8px;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-transform: uppercase;}

   li:hover{
     border-bottom:3px solid #666666;}
```

Comment: You can use pseudo-elements (e.g. ::after) instead of border-bottom for this purpose.

Comment: You cannot hover on a phone.

Comment: @cmprogram, with a mouse and an adapter, anything can happen.

Comment: Mohits comment is probably your best bet, the border is always going to be a board of the element, its a style not an element in its self. However using the pseudo ::after, you can style this to mirror a border as well as specify its widths and placement.

Comment: true you cant hover on a phone and true with adapters you can, but its annoying on reduced screen on laptop and I was wondering if it could be remedied

Comment: ok so ::after but what would the html be?

Comment: change "display: block;" to "display: inline-block"

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Why you would want to spend valuable time and resources developing for that scenario is beyond me.

Comment: no I want block not inline so menu is on top of each other on reduced screen

Comment: cmprogram  its called education not a job, and when you press the li on a phone the hover appears, simples

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo-elements (like `:after`) for this purpose instead of `border-bottom`. You will get more control using pseudo element as compared to `border`.

You should also add `:focus` etc. states in addition to `:hover` for supporting mobile devices.

```css
.region-li{
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right:20px;
   margin-left:20px;
   font-size:16px;
   font-family: 'codec_cold_triallight';
   color:#666666;
   padding: 8px;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-transform: uppercase;}

   li:hover{
     border-bottom:3px solid #666666;}
   
   .region-li-2{
     position: relative;
   }
   .region-li-2:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: orange;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-left: 50%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.region-li-2:hover{
  border-bottom: none;
}
.region-li-2:hover:after{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="region-li">Button 1</li>
  
  <li class="region-li region-li-2">Button 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Good job

Comment: I tried it but got the same result, let me try again

Comment: @Nick What's the issue you're facing with this approach?

Comment: I added the html and css and the outcome was no different, I assume I am adding it incorrectly, I did get the secondary orange line but it was still stretching the entire length of the screen

Comment: @Nick please note that I have added some css rules to your existing css for the `li` e.g `{position: relative; display: inline-block;}`.